# Наполнение массива

Tags: php

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, помогите заполнить массив, что-то я туплю наверное.

Имеется цикл:

```
foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div h2 a') as $element) {    
    $nameNews = $element->innertext;
    $nameNews = iconv( "UTF-8", "windows-1251", $nameNews); 
}
```

ВОПРОС: Как мне создать массив с данными, наполненный **$nameNews**?

Ну такого вида к примеру:

**$nameNews** - *в данном случае новое значение при проходе цикла*

```
Array
(
    [0] => $nameNews
    [1] => $nameNews
    [3] => $nameNews
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array_nameNews = array();

foreach($html->find('div.narrow_column div h2 a') as $element) {    
    $nameNews = $element->innertext;
    $nameNews = iconv( "UTF-8", "windows-1251", $nameNews); 
    $array_nameNews[] = $nameNews;
}

print_r($arrayNamenews);
```

Comment: Блестяще, СПАСИБО огромное :) !